# How to update a data in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a data in mongodb using nodejs. I want the total data to be updated by +1 once a user creates a transaction. But I don't have any idea of it. Because there is no value coming back. like req.body, that I can pass in.

```js
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  total: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passortLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

app.post("/bitcoin", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  client.createTransaction({ currency1: "USD", currency2: "BTC", amount: 500 },
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { total: +1 }, function(error,updated) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("error occured " + error);
            return res.redirect("/dashboard");
          } else {
            console.log("total updated" + updated);
          }
        });
        var coinPayment = result;
        res.redirect(coinPayment.status_url);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

*It console.logs this below and it does not update any work around for this*

```
total updated null
```

Comment: Seems that `req.params.id` is not in the collection. So the `findByIdAndUpdate` find nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you have not declared id in params.

```
app.post('/bitcoin/:id',function(req, res){ /* Some stuff */})
```

Update Query

```
User.update({_id : req.params.id},{$inc: {total:1}})
```

Comment: yeah thanks it is working correctly +1 to you. I had no knowledge of the $inc. :) @Rahul Sharma